# want a dotted line under my navbar but border-bottom-style: dotted; doesnt do it for me?

Tags: html, css, navbar

im building a homepage for a school assignment 
and now the homestyle got a dotted line,
now i wanna use a dotted line under my navbar 
using ( border-bottom-style: dotted; ) doesnt give me a dotted
line under my navbar, hope someone can tell me why its not working?

Thnx !

```css
                           /*Topnav*/
.topnav { 
    width: 100%; 
    float: center; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0; 
    background-color: #C9FD99;
}

.topnav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.topnav a {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
    color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color:#7BFC06;
}
```

```html
                           <!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
 <nav>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">abonneren</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your border-bottom-style:dotted;?

Comment: Also note that there is no `float: center;` !

Comment: well its not working so i got it out again

Comment: what do u mean with there is no float: center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `border-bottom-style` can create a dotted bottom border with some default values. But I would define all needed parameters to get the expected border.

I tried this with Google Chrome and get a default border width of 3px and border-color of black. The default values can be different on other browsers and other projects (using `normalize.css` or similar reset rules).

You can define a border using [`border-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom). With `border-bottom` you can set the width (`border-bottom-width`), the style (`border-bottom-style`) and the color (`border-bottom-color`) of the bottom border.

```css
.topnav { 
  width: 100%; 
  float: center; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0; 
  background-color: #C9FD99;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted black;
}
.topnav ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.topnav ul li {
  display: inline; 
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.topnav a {
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}
.topnav a:link {
  color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color:#7BFC06;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">abonneren</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh this is helpfull thanks ! now i know why it didnt work with only border-style-bottom , thnx allot !

Answer (score 1):

You need to define border-bottom first.

```css
/*Topnav*/
.topnav { 
    width: 100%; 
    float: center; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0; 
    background-color: #C9FD99;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
}

.topnav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.topnav a {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
    color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color:#7BFC06;
}
```

```html
<!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
 <nav>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">abonneren</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to view a dotted border under the navbar, you need to define the border first :-
border-bottom : 1px dotted black, "1px is the thickness", "dotted is the style" and "black colour" You can change the thickness and colour of border as per your requirement .. Here is the code :-

```
.topnav { 
    width: 100%; 
    float: center; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0; 
    background-color: #C9FD99;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.topnav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.topnav a {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
    color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color:#7BFC06;
}
```

```html
                           <!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">abonneren</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the **border-bottom: dotted;**.
This just worked fine for me.

Comment: how come it works like that and not with border-style-bottom ?

Comment: I believe, It is because you don't define the width and color of the border. So it ends up as an incomplete border

Comment: yea i know now why it got explained pretty well above , that helped allot to know what i did wrong , and helps to learn so thank all of u ! :)

Answer (score 0):

i see there is no border-bottom in your .topnav class.
Add border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
* 2px is thickness
* dotted is style
* black is color of the line.